I am unable to open the login page for ethernet since I use my college ethernet. I use an ethernet to type C adapter. Please help
I basically use a college ethernet which opens up a login page where I need to put my college id to access the internet,without it I wont have access. The login page should open automatically but in my case, I do not see the login page on connecting to the ethernet, I am not sure why am I not able to see the login page automatically ,without it I wont be able to connect to internet.When I connect and switch on wired network, no college login page comes up. I am not sure why is this happening to me and how do I fix it, other ubuntu users in my college do not face this issue, they get the automatic login page when they connect to the college ethernet. So I probably think it must be due to the Ethernet Adapter I am using, can someone suggest me a fix on how do I make the login page appear on Firefox so I can connect to the ethernet.
This is the result for command sudo lshw -C network
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller [1T1R]
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 40:1a:58:c7:33:11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.8.0-47-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.30.55.218 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:82 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fce00000-fcefffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enx006f00010316
       serial: 00:6f:00:01:03:16
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772B USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=10.42.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s


Please [edit] your question and add more details. What do you want to achieve? What exactly are you trying? What happens? What do you expect? What do you mean with "the login page for ethernet"?
